# Need to save user's name via AlertDialog that shows only once

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog that shows when a button is pressed; saves the user's name when the Alert "Done" button is pressed; then moves user to another activity. What I am trying to figure out is how to present the AlertDialog only on the first press of this layout button that presents the AlertDialog, so that when the user comes back to this part of the app, and presses the same layout button, the AlertDialog doesn't show, and the user does not have to type their name in again. Here is the code that's not working:

```
    public class CloseoutActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences prefs2;
String prefs2String="";
boolean firstRun = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_closeout);

 // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
        // does not behave as a button
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }


}

public void closeoutCashButtonPressed (View closeoutCashButtonPressedView){

if(firstRun){   

     AlertDialog.Builder builder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder3.setTitle("    Please enter your full name");
     final EditText input3 = new EditText(this);
     input3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
     builder3.setView(input3);
     builder3.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prefs2String = input3.getText().toString();

            prefs2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefs2Editor = prefs2.edit();
            String userName1 = input3.getText().toString();
            prefs2Editor.putString("userName", userName1);
            prefs2Editor.commit();

            launchIntent1();

        }
    });

    builder3.show();
}

firstRun = false;



}

public void launchIntent1(){

    Intent displayCloseoutCashButtonSignal = new Intent (this, CloseoutCashButtonSignal.class);
    displayCloseoutCashButtonSignal.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(displayCloseoutCashButtonSignal);
```

With this code, the AlertDialog keeps popping up when I come back around to this part of the app. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your `firstRun` flag in `SharedPrefs` or some other permanent storage. Every time you run that `Activity` your flag is going to be `true` otherwise. If this is the only place that you are storing the `username` then you should simply be able to check the `SharedPrefs` if the name exists and if it does then continue as you want but if it does not then you can add the name and show the `Dialog`

Comment: You're welcome! Hope it works for you. I appreciate you accepting the answer but you should make sure it works first in the future in case the answerer missed something